# Celery beat args: list vs. tuple

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

The [Celery docs describe](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#available-fields) how you can pass positional arguments to your beat-scheduled tasks as a list or tuple.

I have a task that takes a single argument, a list of integers:

```
@shared_task
def schedule_by_ids(ids):
  ...
```

My celerybeat schedule looks like this:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'schedule_by_ids': {
        'task': 'myproj.app.tasks.schedule_by_ids',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/10', hour='8-21'),
        'args': ([1,]),
    },
}
```

My task fails with an "int is not iterable" `TypeError`. According the my monitor (celery flower) the args are passed as `[1]`.

When I make the args a list, like `[[1]]`, the arg shows up in the monitor as `[[1]]` and it works fine.

My questions are: How is it passing the args when it is a tuple? Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
([1,])
```

That's not a tuple. That's just `[1,]` in grouping parentheses. If you want a 1-element tuple, you need to put a comma in it like so, to distinguish it from just a parenthesized expression:

```
([1,],)
```

I suspect you may have misplaced the comma, and you meant to do this:

```
([1],)
```